# How to use mantine UI with next 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mantine

I was trying to use mantine UI with NextJS 13 using the app directory,
I have to wrap everything in the `MantineProvider` component but I don't know where to put it.

I tried this

layout.js

```
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-head-element */
import { MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core';
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <MantineProvider
    withGlobalStyles
    withNormalizeCSS
    theme={{
      /** Put your mantine theme override here */
      colorScheme: 'dark',
    }}>
      <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </MantineProvider>
    
  );
}
```

and it didn't work
so, is there any solution??

Comment: what do you mean by App directory here?

Comment: It's the new way of doing things in nextjs 13 instead of using the pages directory you use the app directory

Answer (score 28):

So I've been interested in solving this problem too.

Step 1 is moving third-party providers to a "client-only" component.
*[See here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#rendering-third-party-context-providers-in-server-components)*

The next step is to [follow this thread](https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues/2815) on mantine's github, while they work out compatibility issues with emotion & next13

Lastly, [this seems to be the only official implementation example](https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine-next-template/tree/next-13-app/app) on Mantine's github using Mantine with the new Next.js app directory.
Here's how they approached it:

*/app/emotion.tsx*

```
"use client";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import { useEmotionCache, MantineProvider } from "@mantine/core";
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation";

export default function RootStyleRegistry({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const cache = useEmotionCache();
  cache.compat = true;
  
  useServerInsertedHTML(() => (
    <style
      data-emotion={
        `${cache.key} ${Object.keys(cache.inserted).join(" ")}`
      }
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: Object.values(cache.inserted).join(" "),
      }}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <MantineProvider withGlobalStyles withNormalizeCSS>
        {children}
      </MantineProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  )
}
```

*/app/layout.tsx*

```
import RootStyleRegistry from './emotion';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
   <html lang="en-US">
     <head />
     <body>
       <RootStyleRegistry>{children}</RootStyleRegistry>
     </body>
   </html>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you get it working

Comment: @nicolasangela this approach worked perfectly for me, fwiw. Thank you!

Comment: When using this code, I'm getting this error: `error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Any ideas about why?

Comment: @ErzaScarlet, i don't know why, but i convert RootStyleRegistry to arrow function instead of function, it works

Comment: `
"use client";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import { useEmotionCache, MantineProvider } from "@mantine/core";
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation";

const RootStyleRegistry = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
      ....
  );
};

export default RootStyleRegistry;

`

Answer (score 2):

I faced issues with this combo too (running Mantine 6.0.x + NextJS 13 with `appDir` enabled). My mistake was that I was enclosing next-auth's SessionProvider within the providers.tsx, and as the topmost item. This messed up the styles loading and mantine styles were not loading till a route change.

Here is the sample code that works for me:

`providers.tsx`

```
"use client";
...
...
return (
        <ColorSchemeProvider ...>
            <MantineProvider withGlobalStyles withNormalizeCSS ...>
                <ModalsProvider>
                    <SpotlightProvider ...>
                        {children}
                    </SpotlightProvider>
                </ModalsProvider>
                {/* Notifications system */}
                <Notifications .../>
            </MantineProvider>
        </ColorSchemeProvider>
    );
```

and in the root `layout.tsx`

```
const RootLayout = ( {children,}: {children: ReactNode} ) => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
            <SessionProvider>
                <Providers>
                    {children}
                </Providers>
            </SessionProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

PS: I also faced `Error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ...`  that Erza Scarlet mentioned in the previous answer's comment. To fix it, I migrated all my `export default function Fn()` to **default var exports** (`const`s with arrow fns) and also updated React, NextJs and Mantine to the latest versions. That fixed it.